# Newton's method for Kirchhoff's laws

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, physics

Consider an electrical circuit with a resistance ($R$), a coil ($L$) and a capacitor ($C$) in parallel. According to Kirchhoff's laws, the impedance $Z = Z(ω)$ of the circuit $RLC$ can be expressed, as a function of the angular frequency $ω$, by the equation
$$
\frac{1}{Z} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{R^2}+\left(\omega C−\frac{1}{ωL}\right)^2\,}.
$$

Considering
$R = 225\Omega\, [\mathrm{ohm}]$,
$C = 0.6 \times 10^{−6}F\, [\mathrm{farad}]$,
$L = 0.5H\, [\mathrm{henry}]$,
determine by Newton's method an approximate value of one of the values of $\omega$, which result in an impedance of $Z = 75\Omega$. Calculate $3$ iterations and obtain an error estimate for this approximation.

Comment: You want to solve the equation for $\omega$, given $Z$, $R$, $C$, and $L$? Do I have this correct?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried this:

$$f(ω) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{R^2}+\left(ωC−\dfrac{1}{ωL}\right)^2}} - Z.$$

Comment: Wait a second, the question asks you to find $\omega$, not $f(\omega)$. You should have only $\omega$ on one side and expression involving just the other constants on the other side

Comment: @H.sapiensrex. What Teresa properly wrote is that we look for the zero of function $f(\omega)$